# Python syntax help: 'return [x] if [x != e] for [e] in [array]'

Tags: python

I am new to Python and wanted to explore it's pseudo-code like syntax to solve the following problem:

```
# x is 0, 1 or 2
arr = [0, 1, 2]
```

I want to return any element in `arr` that is not equal to `x`

My intuition:

```
return x if x != element for element in arr
```

I have tried to complete the conditional with an `else` clause. Still, the syntax is invalid

What is my mistake? What is a correct one-line solution (if any exists)

Thanks!

Comment: `return [i for i in arr if i != x]`

Comment: Do you want to return *any* element that meets your criteria or *every* element that meets it?

Comment: Thank you patrick! The return type is a array, how can I return just the first  (or any single) `i` that satisfies the condition?

Answer (score 2):

`return [element for element in arr if element != x]`

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return one element from your list matching a certain condition (in this case the condition is `!=x`), you can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next).

```
return next(item for item in arr if item!=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. Just put the `if` last. This will return a generator:

```
def f(ls, e):
    return (x for x in ls if x != e)
```

You can also return a list instead:

```
def f(ls, e):
    return [x for x in ls if x != e]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary if statement as given below:

```
def f(x,arr):
    return x if x in arr else None
```

Or you can use list comprehension if you want return all elements contains in `arr`, as you can see below:

```
def f(x,arr):
    return [y for y in arr if y in x] #here x is a list
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension:

```
return [a for a in arr if a != x]
```